# Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: require - React Native

Tags: react-native

Just got a project that was using expo and have to migrate it to 0.62.

I've been stuck on an issue for a week, when building the app I get "unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: require".

Here's my devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",

    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.2.6",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.2.7",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
```

Here's my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ]
}
```

Here's my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

I tried resetting the cache, deleting node_modules, ... and pretty much every thing that was proposed for this issue on GitHub and StackOverflow but nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: The error comes from an other file where you use require

Comment: @simon thanks for your reply, do you have any idea where to look?

Comment: hmmmm... The files where there is a "require" ?